# Changing one element in a vector within a function

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing

I want to change a single element in a vector:

```
function vecteur_avec_delai=delai(input_vecteur, iteration)
    vecteur_avec_delai(iteration,1) =  input_vecteur(iteration,1);
end
```

`input_vecteur` is a vector of size 6001 -by- 1 filled with the same value: `61.46` , and `vecteur_avec_delai = ones(6001,1)`

I want to change one value of `vecteur_avec_delai` to 61.46, so to still have a vector of length 6001, filled with ones except one cell with a value equal to 61.46, thus the `vecteur_avec_delai(iteration,1) =  input_vecteur(iteration,1);`

When I run :

```
vecteur_avec_delai=delai(input_vecteur, iteration)
```

It compiles but gives me for output a `vecteur_avec_delai` of size (`iteration, 1` ) filled with `0`s except for the last value equal to `61.46`.

When I try this operation "manually" (directly in the MATLAB command window), it works, so why doesn't it when I go through this function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't declared `vecteur_avec_delai` as input into the function. This boils down to calling `A(10,1) = 1` in a clean command window: it creates a 10-by-1 vector with 9 zeros and a `1` at the end. Instead, first declare your array to be ones and then set only this required element:

```
function vecteur_avec_delai=delai(input_vecteur, iteration)
    vecteur_avec_delai = ones(size(input_vecteur));
    vecteur_avec_delai(iteration,1) =  input_vecteur(iteration,1);
end
```

Or, given your comment about it working in the command window, simply add `vecteur_avec_delai` to the inputs of the function (you might want to change the names of the input and output variables to not be the same for clarity). Functions are closed name-spaces, i.e. they have their own "workspace" so to say, and cannot see anything outside of that function, hence the need to declare all inputs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. However, in the long term, I need vecteur_avec_delai to be defined outside of the function as it will change throughout my simulation and I need to keep it updated at each call

Comment: @elle.delle yea, so just add it as an input to the function. Functions are closed name-spaces, i.e. they have their own "workspace" so to say, and cannot see anything outside of that function. Thus, you'll need to set it as input to the function (or set it to be a global variable, if you know what you're doing)

Comment: @Adriaan FYI stand-alone functions have their own private workspaces, but nested functions can see the workspaces of the caller.